# How to increase the speed of a procedure via pyspark/hadoop/etc?

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, pyspark, bigdata

I have a large directory of large matrices and I am applying some expensive operations to such matrices. The pipeline looks like this:

```
Directory -> extract matrices -> apply operations -> save in a .csv file
```

Note that I wrapped into a function the previous "pipeline". So far with python's multiprocessing library I was able to apply the previous pipeline in 1 week. However, I am curious if it's possible to "parallelize" in a spark map-reduce way the previous function. Therefore, does my task can be enhanced with pysparks map reduce?, how can I enhance the speed? (I just have two laptops), which other way do you guys recommend me to increase the speed of my pipeline without modifying the function?.

Comment: Try Dask before jumping to Spark

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing to do is run on bigger computers.  Spark and Map-Reduce were not really designed for laptops, they were meant for servers.  You can rent servers (AWS, Google Compute Engine) and run your pipeline on larger servers with more memory (I would recommend 32GB min ideally 64GB or higher) with more CPU cores (4 or more).  You can always mock your test on the free tier (both AWS and Google have free tiers) before you actually rent servers.  After that, you throw more servers at it.

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ and https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing has pricing details, but you'd be surprised what you can buy for under $2/hr.